# LazyColumn is slower than Column with vertical scroll

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I have product cell which I want to display on the list, I've used LazyColumn but performance was terrible, I couldn't find why it is so slow. Then I've switched LazyColumn to Column and all of the sudden scrolling is super smooth

LazyColumn version:

```
LazyColumn() {
    items(cartItems, key = {it.cartItem.id}) { cartItemData ->
        CartItemWithActions(data = cartItemData)
        Divider(color = colorResource(id = R.color.separator_line))
    }
}
```

Column version

```
val state = rememberScrollState()
Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(state)) {
    cartItems.forEach { cartItemData ->
        CartItemWithActions(data = cartItemData)
        Divider(color = colorResource(id = R.color.separator_line))
    }
}
```

CartItemWithActions is my product cell with image that I'm loading using glide and couple of texts

[image]

HWUI for LazyColumn version

[image]

HWUI for Column

[image]

Can anyone provide hint why LazyColumn is slower than Column?

**UPDATE**

It seems LazyColumn scroll much better when LazyColumn is setup this way

```
LazyColumn() {
    items(
        count = cartItems.size,
        key = {
            cartItems[it].cartItem.id
        },
        itemContent = { index ->
            val cartItemData = cartItems[index]
            CartItemWithActions(data = cartItemData)
            Divider(
                color = colorResource(id =R.color.separator_line)
            )
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Try to run it in a release build

Comment: I've tried it's not helping

Comment: I've personally experience it too, but it seemed to go away after you scroll randomly for five seconds continuously, upon every app startup

Comment: This doesn't happen with simple stuff like `Text`, but with heavy custom Composables, this did seem like an issue to me as well.

Comment: @MARSK yes, for simple layout it's ok

Comment: I thought it would go away in the release build and so I ignored it.

Comment: You can try to move the alpha to a graphicsLayer.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov I've added more details, but since it's contains many references to other functions it's hard to include all of it here

Comment: @Francesc, thx I will do that, however even without alpha it's the same

Comment: Hey can we celebrate it? It is exactly the 2500th question on the `android-jetpack-compose` tag!

Comment: So no celebration

Comment: @PhilipDukhov WebImage is using glide to load image, commenting it out makes no difference

Comment: I've added HWUI render profile for both versions, it seems like LazyColumn takes much more time to layout elements than for Column version

Comment: @MaciejPrzybylski try commenting out all children one by one to see find the one which is causing the troubles

Comment: @PhilipDukhov I've tried that in the first place but I cant't find what is causing it. as soon as I put something more than Text it starts to lag

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that initialising LazyColumn in this way solves my issue

```
LazyColumn() {
    items(
        count = cartItems.size,
        key = {
            cartItems[it].cartItem.id
        },
        itemContent = { index ->
            val cartItemData = cartItems[index]
            CartItemWithActions(data = cartItemData)
            Divider(
                color = colorResource(id =R.color.separator_line)
            )
        }
    )
}
```

However I still don't know why

Comment: It works better because using the key parameter gives Jetpack Compose a similar power to DiffUtil in RecyclerView.

Comment: doesn't work with compose 1.2.0. same sluggish behaviour

Comment: @isudansh same with me.

Comment: Is sluggish behaviour resolved now ?

Comment: I still see laggy behavior.

Comment: @HBB20 I have the same issue. LazyColumn is extremely laggy. Is this related to compose version? does downgrading the version work?

Comment: Did you find out if the compose version affected this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes so weird noone talking about this s. Normal column like 5x faster and smooth than lazy column. Problem is when loading data in normal column freezing screen like 2 second for 50 card but after 0 freezing or slowing etc.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33538443)