# Laggy Lazy Column Android Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, coil

I've created a whole app in **Jetpack Compose**. However, the performances on the `Lazy Column` are pretty bad and it does not make any sense. `Lazy Column` should be the substitution of `RecyclerView`, but `RecyclerView` works much better at the moment.

I made a `Lazy Column` with headers and `Lazy Rows` as items (basically a nested list). As you can see there are images but I used the **Coil library** so everything should be loaded in a separate thread. I've already seen these discussions: [link1](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/n61qxh/jetpack_compose_lazycolumn_laggy/), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69856439/lazycolumn-is-slower-than-column-with-vertical-scroll). But it seems like there's not a solution to this problem, even though now **Jetpack Compose** is stable.

Did any of you find a way to get better performances or should I substitute this `Lazy Rows` with a `RecyclerView`?

Here's a screen of the page:

[image]

Answer (score 96, accepted):

#### Things will speed up your Lazy List

1. **If you're in debug mode, that's normal**. Don't worry if your app is laggy in debugging. It's completely fine. Just create the APK in release mode (Build -> Generated Signed Bundle/APK), which might solve your problem. This happens because when in debugging, Compose translates bytecode in runtime using JIT. Make sure you're also using the **R8 compiler** in the release build. This is extremely important to improve general performance.
2. **Set a key for your item**. Initialize your Lazy list like this.

```kotlin
LazyColumn() {
    items(
        count = cartItems.size,
        key = {
            cartItems[it].cartItem.id
        },
        itemContent = { index ->
            val cartItemData = cartItems[index]
            CartItemWithActions(data = cartItemData)
            Divider(
                color = colorResource(id =R.color.separator_line)
            )
        }
    )
}
```

Setting a key works similar to the `DiffUtil` class in `RecyclerView`. Check the [Maciej Przybylski's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69856439/lazycolumn-is-slower-than-column-with-vertical-scroll).

3. Make sure every variable is using the `remember{}` block.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyComposable() {
    ...
    val wrongList = myViewModel.getList() // <- Don't do this
    val correctList = remember { myViewModel.getList() } // <- Do this
    ...
}
```

4. You can also use `contentType`, which defines the type of object in a list. This is useful if you have headers or different types of objects in your list. Learn more [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListScope).
5. **Baseline Profiles**. If you've tried everything but your list is still missing frames this might be it. In this [talk](https://www.droidcon.com/2022/06/28/making-apps-blazing-fast-with-baseline-profiles/), Rahul Ravikumar (Google engineer) reveals how Baseline Profiles improve performances up to 40%. What's this? Compose is a library and not native XML. This means that every time you execute your app, the code has to be translated at runtime. You can pre-execute and save all this code when installing the app using Baseline Profiles. Check these links: [Baseline Profiles](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/baselineprofiles), [Improving Performance with Baseline Profiles](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/improving-performance-with-baseline-profiles-fdd0db0d8cc6).

Check these resources never to have performance issues again. I highly suggest watching these videos: [Optimizing Render Performance of Jetpack Compose](https://youtu.be/Ry-3xlElUe4), [Performance best practices for Jetpack Compose](https://youtu.be/EOQB8PTLkpY), and reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71807439/how-optimize-jetpack-compose-list-performance).

#### A Good News

Generally speaking, Jetpack Compose is not great in terms of performance compared to XML. We now know this issue is due to the way Modifiers have been created. I highly suggest you watch [this video](https://youtu.be/BjGX2RftXsU). The good news is that the Jetpack Compose team has been working on a new way to improve performance for a few months now. This new way leverages the use of `Modifier.Node` to avoid executing lots of useless operations under the hood. The best thing about this approach is that you won't be required to change anything in your code, and it will be completely retro-compatible.

**Available from Jetpack Compose `1.5.0`**

#### Original Answer

SOLVED! Reading this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/oatiur/why_simple_app_with_jetpack_compose_is_5x_times/h3jj1i4/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) I found out the problem is only in the **debug version**. It seems crazy but it's true. That's because debug versions of Compose apps have a lot going on under the hood which impacts performance (pretty similar to what happens with Flutter). To solve the problem **the only thing you need to do** is to create a release version of your app. To do that, go to **Build** -> **Generated Signed Bundle/APK**. Create the key and then select **release**.

Enjoy your smooth app!

Comment: Also consider watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ry-3xlElUe4 which contains a lot of great information about how to optimize a compose application (including the information you discovered from reddit).

Comment: Yep, I saw that. Incredibly useful!

Comment: Doesn't work with compose 1.4.0-alpha02. same sluggish behaviour.

Comment: Same issue happened to me, it was fixed after "Build -> Generated Signed Bundle/APK.", so app only lags on debug mode

Comment: I don't need to build an apk to see better performances. Just putting the build variant as release solves performance issues in my case.

Comment: Thanks for this, adding `count` and `key` really improved performance for me