# How optimize JetPack Compose list performance?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a simple composable function which contains LazyColumn:

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen(itemList: List<Item>) {
    LazyColumn {
        intems(itemList) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works great, but my ViewState(`itemList`) should change when the scroll reaches some position index. That's why I add the following lines to my composable function:

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen(itemList: List<Item>) {
    val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
    viewModel.onPositionChanged(lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex)
    LazyColumn(state = lazyListState) {
        intems(itemList) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works as I expected, but performance has noticeably deteriorated. How I can fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. You're reading the state directly in the Composable with `lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex`, this causes continues recompositions - each time any part of `lazyListState` changes, e.g. on each scrolled pixel.
2. You're making `viewModel.onPositionChanged` call directly from composable. It's recommended to make such calls from special side effect functions, read more about the topic in [thinking in compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model) and side effects [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects).

In this case `LaunchedEffect` with `snapshotFlow` can be used like this:

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    snapshotFlow { lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex }
        .collect(viewModel::onPositionChanged)
}
```

You can also face same problem when you need to update the view depending on the list state. In such case [`derivedStateOf`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#derivedStateOf(kotlin.Function0)) should be used: it'll cause recomposition only when the calculated value actually changes.

```
val firstVisibleItemIndex by remember {
    derivedStateOf {
        lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex
    }
}
```