# How to use the remember function on the collectAsStateWithLifecycle function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How to use the remember function on the collectAsStateWithLifecycle function i tried in this way but couldn't collect the latest value the initial list is empty . I wanted to wrap it remember function because my lazy Column was lagging while scrolling. so that next time the composable that called the remember function recomposes, the cached result is used instead of recalculating the result. This can improve performance by avoiding unnecessary calculations.Got some idea from this answer [ways to improve the Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70596559/13075886)
but if you check my logs my data is printing but initial lists are empty and later this list is populated with the data

```
@Composable
fun SampleHomeScreenUploadSection(
navController: NavController,
viewModel: SampleHomeScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {


val getAllContents by viewModel.mainContentsData.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

val stateGetAllContents = remember { getAllContents }


Scaffold {

    LazyColumn() {
        itemsIndexed(stateGetAllContents) { index, allContent ->

        
            MainContentCollections(getAllContent = allContent, onContentClick = {}, index = index)

        }
    }
```

viewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class SampleHomeScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(
private val useCases: UseCases,
private val checkRep: AdminRepository
) : ViewModel() {


private val _mainContentsData = MutableStateFlow<List<GetAllContent>>(emptyList())
val mainContentsData: StateFlow<List<GetAllContent>> = _mainContentsData.asStateFlow()

private val _bannerContentData = MutableStateFlow<List<Banner>>(emptyList())
val bannerContentData: StateFlow<List<Banner>> = _bannerContentData.asStateFlow()

private val _productContentData = MutableStateFlow<List<ReceiveProduct>>(emptyList())
val productContentData: StateFlow<List<ReceiveProduct>> = _productContentData.asStateFlow()

private val _mainCategoryData = MutableStateFlow<List<MainCategory>>(emptyList())


init {

    viewModelScope.launch {
        checkRep.getAllMainContent().collect { allContent ->
            allContent.forEach { mainContent ->
                if (mainContent.contentType == "Products") {
                    viewModelScope.launch {
                        checkRep.getProductContentFromFirestore(mainContent.contentTags!!)
                            .collect { productContent ->
                                _productContentData.value = productContent
                                mainContent.products =
                                    _productContentData.value.toMutableList()
                                Log.i(TAG, "check2: $mainContent")
                                updatingMainList(mainContent)
                                _productContentData.value = emptyList()
                            }
                    }
                }

                if (mainContent.contentType == "Banners") {
                    viewModelScope.launch {
                        checkRep.getBannerContentFromFirestore(mainContent.contentTags!!)
                            .collect { bannerContent ->
                                _bannerContentData.value = bannerContent
                                mainContent.banners =
                                    _bannerContentData.value.toMutableList()
                                Log.i(TAG, "CheckBB: $mainContent")
                                updatingMainList(mainContent)
                                _bannerContentData.value = emptyList()
                            }
                    }
                }

                if (mainContent.contentType == "Categories") {
                    viewModelScope.launch {
                        checkRep.getAllCategoriesFromFirestore().collect { mainCategories ->
                            _mainCategoryData.value = mainCategories
                            mainContent.categories = _mainCategoryData.value.toMutableList()
                            Log.i(TAG, "CheckCC: $mainContent")
                            updatingMainList(mainContent)

                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

}

private fun updatingMainList(getAllContent: GetAllContent) {
    _mainContentsData.value = _mainContentsData.value + getAllContent

}

}
```

My log statement collectAsStateWithLLifecycle() function
[image]

Comment: You don't need to `remember` it at all, it is already state - that's why the method name as `AsState` in it. What makes you think you need to `remember` it? It sounds like maybe the issue is actually with your `mainContentsData`. Can you include your `SampleHomeScreenViewModel` class?

Comment: Included my viewModel. as you mentioned it is already 'AsState' . i don' t need to use 'remember' function . but still the LazyColumn is lagging