Inflate activity's layout asynchronously while other activity is running
I work on an app that consists of two activities, call them A and B.

A is a main activity that appears after launch.

B is an activity with a very heavy layout that needs to be inflated.


If I synchronously switch from A to B using startActivity, and then inflate B's layout in its onCreate, it takes a very long time that the user has to wait.
Is it possible somehow to asynchronously inflate B's layout until starting it, while A is running and the user does some actions on A?
I tried AsyncLayoutInflater, but I didn't find the way how to inflate the layout of another activity, until starting it.
If it is not possible, could you please suggest any other approaches or workarounds to solve this issue?
UPD.: the problem disappeared after creation of APK in release mode.
(Build -> Generated Signed Bundle/APK)
Laggy Lazy Column Android Compose

I would start by revisiting your decision to have two activities, rather than a single activity with two fragments or composables to represent the screens. Next, I would revisit the layout and see what approaches could make it be less heavy (e.g., use RecyclerView, or replace the layout with a composable).

I rewrote the app using Jetpack Compose, but it hasn't become faster, actualy it became even a bit slower. But I liked Jetpack Compose and will continue development this way, so thank you for the advice =)
Today I found out, that for increasing the speed, I had to make an APK in release mode (Build -> Generated Signed Bundle/APK). It immediately became several times faster than it was in debug mode. The performance improved for both XML and Compose versions of my app.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70592694/laggy-lazy-column-android-compose
